# Elixir: Select mupliple elements from a list based on index

Tags: list, elixir, enumerable

Assuming I have a list, is there a built-in operator or function to select elements based on a list of indices?

For example, an operator something like this `["a", "b", "z"] = alphabet[0, 1, 25]`

An naive implementation of this could be:

```
def select(list, indices) do
  Enum.map(indices, &(Enum.at(list, &1)))
end
```

If it doesn't exist, it this a deliberate omission to avoid lists being treated like arrays?

An example of what I'm attempting that made me want this, in case I'm asking the wrong question: Given a list, I want to select the first, middle, and last elements, then calculate the median of the three. I was doing `length(list)` to calculate the length, then I wanted to use this operator/function to select the three elements I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the built in operator does not exist. And each time I have to fetch several elements in a list, I use the same implementation as yours. It is quite short and simple to recreate and I suspect it is the reason why there are no off-the shelf solution in elixir.

Another reason I can think of, is as you pointed out, the fact that lists aren't arrays: when you want to access one element, you have to access all the elements before it, therefore accessing elements by a list of index is not a relevant function, because list are not optimized to be used that way.

Still I often access a list of element with a list of index, meaning that I might not be using elixir the right way.